# Blob detection not working

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to detect blobs in an image but its not working somehow. Basically I want to determine number of circles.

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
# Read image
im = cv2.imread("K.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Change thresholds
params.minThreshold = 10
params.maxThreshold = 200

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 50

# Filter by Circularity
params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = 0.75

# Filter by Convexity
params.filterByConvexity = True
params.minConvexity = 0.87

# Filter by Inertia
params.filterByInertia = True
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.7

detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)


# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(im)
print len(keypoints)
# Draw detected blobs as red circles.
# cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures
# the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob

im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255),
                                      cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

# Show blobs
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
if cv2.waitKey(0) and 0xff==27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here's the input image:

[image]

Comment: You seem to be on the right path. Here is some material you can read to figure out why it's not working for you: [Blob detection using openCV](https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have figured out the solution.

When it comes to detection of blobs; you are identifying outliers/unwanted objects in the image. Hence these so called **blobs/outliers** are assumed to be black/grayish on a plain background. In other words, blobs are assumed to be easily identifiable against a white background.

When you perform blob detection against a gray scale image of the original image, the background present is black as shown:

[image]

Against a black background **blob detection** finds nothing :(

#### What do I do?

This is what I did. It was just a single line of a hack. I blurred the gray scale image and then inverted it using `inverted_img = cv2.bitwise_not(blur)`

I then passed the obtained image to the blob detection function. And this is what I got:

[image]

I am able to obtain the number of blobs present as well:

```
number = 0
for i in keypoints[0:]:
    number = number + 1    

print "Number of blobs:",number
```

And this is what I got in the console screen:

[image]

Comment: Point Noted. BTW instead of using loop to calculate the no. of blob you could have simply used len(keypoints). Thanks again.

Comment: Just a simple question,how exactly did the statement `inverted_img = cv2.bitwise_not(blur)` made the code run. And one more thing I'm unable to obtain circles of same radius as the blob(In my case the circles are smaller than the blob)

Comment: Try `cv2.imshow()` of the inverted image and see for yourself. You will understand. To get better radius, try performing Gaussian blur before blob detection. That is what I did

Comment: Hey, is there a way I could contact you incase I get any doubts. I'm a noob to image processing maybe you can help me.